# Make Android Button Chamfered Corner

Tags: java, android, xml, button, xml-drawable

Is it possible to make chamfered corner in Android Button like this (pointy corner)??

[image]

All reference i've searched is to create rounded corner, not chamfered.

Please help. Thank you for any answer.

Comment: You can use a nine patch drawable to create this background

Comment: A nine patch would work, but Android is going in the direction of vectors these days, not so hard to draw what you want (  [nine patch](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html) is a special scalable image)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Button` and set this image as background `android:background="@drawable/chamfered_edge_img"` (i hav used above image as chamfered_edge_img, u can use same image without text and add text to button with `android:text="My Button Name"`)

**Code:**

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@drawable/lcoyg"
        style="?selectableItemBackground"
        />
```

**Result:**

[image]